# Удалить одинаковые элементы из ассоциативного массива

Tags: javascript

У меня есть объект

```
var data = [{"кришна":"верно1","topic_id":"39875"},
{"кришна":"верно2","topic_id":"39875"},
{"харе":"madare","topic_id":"39872"},
{"харе":"верно3","topic_id":"39875"},
{"харе":"fufuf","topic_id":"39873"},
{"8-()":"gagaga","topic_id":"39871"}
];
```

Мне нужно из него удалить все повторяющиеся элементы по "topic_id".Как тут можно решить этот вопрос?

Comment: Цикл по всем элементам, в цикле операция добавления в новый массив, если объект с `topic_id` не существует в новом массиве.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = [
  {"кришна":"верно1","topic_id":"39875"},
  {"кришна":"верно2","topic_id":"39875"},
  {"харе":"madare","topic_id":"39872"},
  {"харе":"верно3","topic_id":"39875"},
  {"харе":"fufuf","topic_id":"39873"},
  {"8-()":"gagaga","topic_id":"39871"}
]

var newData = []

data.forEach(function(item, i, data){
  if ( !doesIncludeByTopicId(newData, item.topic_id) ){
    newData.push(item)
  }
})

console.log('data = ', data);
console.log('newData = ', newData);

/** Check if an array includes an object with property "topic_id" equal to the option "topic_id"
 *
 * @param {array} array
 * @param {string} topic_id
 *
 * @return {boolean}
 */
function doesIncludeByTopicId(array, topic_id) {

  for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if (array[i].topic_id === topic_id) return true
  }

  return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Предложу более современное и лаконичное решение

```js
const data = [
  {"кришна":"верно1","topic_id":"39875"},
  {"кришна":"верно2","topic_id":"39875"},
  {"харе":"madare","topic_id":"39872"},
  {"харе":"верно3","topic_id":"39875"},
  {"харе":"fufuf","topic_id":"39873"},
  {"8-()":"gagaga","topic_id":"39871"}
];

const uniqueTopicIdsMap = data.reduce((prev, item) => {
  prev[item.topic_id] = item;
  return prev;
},{});

const result = Object.keys(uniqueTopicIdsMap).map(topicId => uniqueTopicIdsMap[topicId]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если речь пошла о современном и лаконичном, то вот вам еще вариант.

```
var data = [
  {"кришна":"верно1","topic_id":"39875"},
  {"кришна":"верно2","topic_id":"39875"},
  {"харе":"madare","topic_id":"39872"},
  {"харе":"верно3","topic_id":"39875"},
  {"харе":"fufuf","topic_id":"39873"},
  {"8-()":"gagaga","topic_id":"39871"}
]

var newData = data.filter(function(elem){
  if (this[elem.topic_id]) return false;
  return this[elem.topic_id] = true
},{})

console.log(data);
console.log(newData);
```